# Compare dates in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I want to compare dates in my CodeIgniter model. In my db, dates are stored as MM/DD/YYYY. Comparison date take from a date picker that uses the MM/DD/YYYY format.

But my model query not working. The date comparison is not done here.

What's the format for comparison?

**Model**

```
   $this->db->where('order_date >=', $first_date);
   $this->db->where('order_date <=', $second_date);
```

Comment: What is your field type? (e.g. DATE, DATETIME, VARCHAR)

Comment: I choose varchar size 255

Comment: use `DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Where..?plz give details

Comment: as @Saty said, please use a right date format. If it looks hard for you, you can use timestamp format for ordering dates.

Comment: @Saty Is It right  $this->db->where('Expiry_date >=', DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y');

Comment: yep its looks correct

Comment: $this->db->where('Expiry_date >=', DATE_FORMAT($first_date,'%m/%d/%Y');

Comment: what is the value of `$first_date`??

Comment: date is like 12/01/2015  (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `str_to_date` function like as

```
$this->db->where("order_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$first_date','%m/%d/%Y') AND str_to_date('$second_date','%m/%d/%Y')");
```

Comment: yes.. `order_date ` BETWEEN str_to_date(12/01/2015,'%m/%d/%Y') AND str_to_date(12/02/2015,'%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: echo result..bt no comparison occured

Comment: Updated my answer dates need to be enclosed within quotes

Comment: Try to echo query and post it within your MySql and check is it working over there

Comment: i got using this quey

Comment: SELECT  `student_name` ,  `order_date` 
FROM  `ms_student` 
WHERE  `order_date` 
BETWEEN  '11/25/2015'
AND  '11/26/2015'

Comment: Try after your query ends but before `return` `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;`

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

use **[STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)**

```
$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(order_date,'%m/%d/%Y') >=", 
STR_TO_DATE($first_date,'%m/%d/%Y'));

$this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(order_date,'%m/%d/%Y') >=", 
STR_TO_DATE($second_date,'%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Comment: order_date,'%m/%d/%Y' here some unexpected %

Comment: using this i got 0 instead of DATE_FORMAT($first_date,'%m/%d/%Y'));

Comment: AND DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= 0
AND DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= 0

Comment: STR_TO_date('12/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y') or try this @Rose

Comment: This goes to some err page

Comment: $this->db->where("STR_TO_DATE(order_date,'%m/%d/%Y') >=", 
STR_TO_DATE($first_date,'%m/%d/%Y'));

Answer (score 0):

**User Inputs**

```
$fDate = $this->input->post("first_date"); // Input date format as mm/dd/yy
$sDate = $this->input->post("first_date"); // Input date format as mm/dd/yy
```

---

**Convert User inputs**

```
$first_date = date_format($fDate,"m/d/Y"); // Output date format as mm/dd/yy
$second_date = date_format($sDate,"m/d/Y"); // Output date format as mm/dd/yy
```

---

**In code**

```
$this->db->where('order_date >=', $first_date);
$this->db->where('order_date <=', $second_date);
```

*Or*

```
$this->db->where('order_date BETWEEN '.$first_date.' and '.$second_date);
```

---

Check datepicker format is `datepicker-popup="mm/dd/yyyy"`